# GTest, expect call on private pointer member

Tags: c++, unit-testing, mocking, googletest

I have a class A such as :

```cpp
// .h
class A {
public:
    A();
    void init();
private:
    B* b;
    C* c;
};

// .cpp

A::A()
{
    b = new B();
    c = new C();
}

A::init()
{
    if (b->foo()){
        // doing hardware operations
        c->on();
    }
    else
    {
        // not doing hardware operations
    }
}
```

with `b.foo()` a method a B returning a boolean value depending a specific B conditions and `c::on()` some method doing operations on hardware.

I'm unit testing class A with gtest / gmock. I know that theorically what is private should remain private, but the whole purpose of my A::init method is to do a specific operation depending on the result of b::foo() which i cannot mock has `b` is private.

Is there a way to verify that depending on b::foo() result, my public method A is doing the right operation ?

Comment: The duckduckgoing term you are looking for is *dependency injection*.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen This would mean that the class instantiating A would need to know B and C to give to A constructor a reference to a  B and C objects

Comment: Possibly but not necessarily. You can keep default constructor initialising them with real values, while having a different constructor that accepts dependencies. If you want to make your class testable, you have to change it anyway.

Comment: I do not like to add some production code for tests purposes, but with the following architecture, maybe i have nothing but this choice

Comment: I'd be tempted to add some const methods to `A` to reveal the internal state to the extent that allows it to be tested. Introducing polymorphism or some other indirection is a _lot_ of extra boilerplate and complicates the code. I use google mocking when I naturally have an abstract base class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need dependency injection.

Assuming that `B` and `C` are representing direct operation on hardware you should abstract this functionality to be able to mock hardware (those `B` and `C`).

This can go like this:

```cpp
// InterfaceBC.h
class IB {
public:
    virtual ~IB() { }

    virtual bool foo() const = 0;
};

class IC {
public:
    virtual ~IC() { }

    virtual void on() = 0;
};

// A.h
class A {
public:
    explicit A(IB* instanceB, IC* instanceC);
    void init();

private:
    IB* const b;
    IC* const c;
};

// A.cpp
A::A(IB* instanceB, IC* instanceC)
    : b { instanceB }
    , c { instanceC }
{
}

void A::init()
{
    if (b->foo()) {
        // doing hardware operations
        c->on();
    } else {
        // not doing hardware operations
    }
}
```

Then you can write proper test for it:

```cpp
// A_test.cpp
using testing::Return;

class MockB : public IB {
public:
    MOCK_METHOD(bool, foo, (), (const override));
};

class MockC : public IC {
public:
    MOCK_METHOD(void, on, (), (override));
};

class StackOverflowTestA : public ::testing::Test
{
public:
    MockB mockB;
    MockC mockC;
    A underTest{&mockB, &mockC};
};

TEST_F(StackOverflowTestA, initOnFooSuccessCOnIsCalled)
{
    EXPECT_CALL(mockB, foo()).WillOnce(Return(true));
    EXPECT_CALL(mockC, on()).Times(1);
    underTest.init();
}

TEST_F(StackOverflowTestA, initOnFooFailureCOnIsNotCalled)
{
    EXPECT_CALL(mockB, foo()).WillOnce(Return(false));
    EXPECT_CALL(mockC, on()).Times(0);
    underTest.init();
}
```

[Live demo](https://godbolt.org/z/G18Wd68oa).